# handleEnd function is not being called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, text-to-speech

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Textarea.css';
import { useSpeechSynthesis } from 'react-speech-kit';

function Textarea(props) {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const [audioURL, setAudioURL] = useState('');

  const { speak } = useSpeechSynthesis();

  const generateAudio = () => {
    speak({ text, onEnd: handleEnd });
    console.log("generateAudio called");
  };

  const handleEnd = (event) => {
    const blob = new Blob([event.target.blob], { type: 'audio/mpeg' });
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    setAudioURL(url);
    console.log('handleEnd called');
  };

  return (
    <>
    <div className="text-area-container">
      <label htmlFor={props.id}>{props.label}</label>
      <textarea
        id={props.id}
        name={props.name}
        placeholder="Type or paste here and get audio file"
        rows={props.rows}
        value={text}
        onChange={(event) => setText(event.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
    <button className='convert-btn' onClick={generateAudio}>Generate audio</button>
    {audioURL && (
    <a href={audioURL} download="audio.mp3" className='download-audio-btn'>
      Download Audio
    </a>
  )}
    </>
  );
}

export default Textarea;
```

Hey, I was building the react Text-to-speech web application using `react-speech-kit`. I am not able to download the audio file as the `handleEnd` function is not being called. Can anyone help me to know what is the issue.

Any help is appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you for your message. I apologize for the inconvenience caused by uploading an image instead of text. Will make sure to follow the guidelines in the future. Thank you for your time and assistance.